Translation of the official title 王府率 (Tang dynasty)
I cannot find too much information about the official title 王府率, mentioned in the 舊唐書‧曹确傳 :

確精儒術，器識謹重，動循法度。懿宗以伶官李可及為威衛將軍，確執奏曰：「臣覽貞觀故事，太宗初定官品令，文武官共六百四十三員，顧謂房玄齡曰：『朕設此官員，以待賢士。工商雜色之流，假令術逾儕類，止可厚給財物，必不可超授官秩，與朝賢君子比肩而立，同坐而食。』太和中，文宗欲以樂官尉遲璋為王府率，拾遺竇洵直極諫，乃改授光州長史。伏乞以兩朝故事，別授可及之官。」帝不之聽。

There is another occurrence of 王府率 in the 舊唐書‧陳夷行傳, suggesting that it is of the 六品 rank :

仙韶院樂官尉遲璋授王府率，右拾遺竇洵直當衙論曰：「伶人自有本色官，不合授之清秩。」鄭覃曰：「此小事，何足當衙論列！王府率是六品雜官，謂之清秩，與洵直得否？此近名也。」嗣復曰：「嘗聞洵直幽，今當衙論一樂官，幽則有之，亦不足怪。」夷行曰：「諫官當衙，只合論宰相得失，不合論樂官。然業已陳論，須與處置。今後樂人每七八年與轉一官，不然，則加手力課三數人。」帝曰：「別與一官。」乃授光州長史，賜洵直絹百疋。夷行尋轉門下侍郎。

Finally, a comment from 胡三省 in 資治通鑒‧卷二百五十 :

⑤樂工李可及善爲新聲，三月，上以可及爲左威衞將軍，曹確諫曰︰「太宗定文武官六百餘員，謂房玄齡曰︰『朕以待天下賢士，工商雜流，不可處也。』〈處，昌呂翻。〉大和中，文宗欲以樂工尉遲璋爲王府率，〈尉，孿勿翻。東宮有十率，諸王有府率。〉拾遺竇洵直諫，卽改光州長史。乞以兩朝故事，別除可及官。」不從。

What would be an adequate translation of the official title 王府率 ? In the texts above, the emperor 文宗 wanted to assign this title to the musician 尉遲璋, so I doubt that it has a military nature like 東宮十率.
[Edit] : 尉遲璋 is actually a 伶官. The musician 李可及 in the aforementioned texts has got the title 威衛將軍, so it's likely that 王府率 has also a military nature.
The Dictionary of Official Titles in Imperial China (Charles O. Hucker) was not helpful on the matter.

one meaning of "率[shuài]" is "leader - 领导者，统帅，首领". I think 王府率 is a supervising position in the prince's residence (王府) in charge of miscellaneous works of the residence (王府琐碎事务).

in the book “御批資治通鑑綱目”, volume 卷五十下 has an annotation (no. 190):

王府率率與帥通音所類反王府之率掌兵仗羽衛之政令總諸曹之事

王府率・率與帥通音・所類反・王府之率・掌兵仗羽衛之政令・總諸曹之事
率與帥通音: the characters “率” and “帥” share the same syllable
所類反: 所 soh2 + 類 lui6 —> sui3
王府之率: the commander of a prince’s mansion
掌兵仗羽衛之政令: superintends the orders of security personnel, guard of honour
總諸曹之事: chief of staffs affairs
so, “王府率”, might be interpreted  as “prince’s mansion chamberlain“  imo
have fun 
